# A question about Polya's urn scheme

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $G_n$ be the number of green balls after the $n^{th}$ draw has been completed and the new ball has been added. Let the urn have $1$ red and $2$ green balls to begin with and say we add $1$ ball of the color drawn at each draw.

Durrett says $P(G_n = m+2) = {n \choose m}\frac{m!(n-m)!}{(n+1)!/2}\rightarrow 2x$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ where $m/n\rightarrow x$. I don't understand where the factor of 2 is coming from? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a typo in the OP. The statement in Durrett's book is as follows:

> $$P(G_n = m+2) = {n \choose m}\frac{(m+1)!(n-m)!}{(n+2)!/2}\rightarrow 2x.$$

Observations: (a) the probability of getting green on the first $m$ draws then red on the next $n − m$ draws is
$$\frac23\cdot\frac3{3+1}\cdot\cdots\cdot\frac{m+1}{3+m-1}\cdot\frac1{3+m}\cdot\frac2{3+m+1}\cdot\cdots\cdot\frac{n-m}{3+n-1}=\frac{(m+1)!(n-m)!}{(n+2)!/2};$$
(b) any other outcome of the first $n$ draws with $m$ green balls drawn and $n-m$ red
balls drawn has the same probability since the denominator remains the same and
the numerator is permuted.

Hence $$P(G_n = m+2) = {n \choose m}\frac{(m+1)!(n-m)!}{(n+2)!/2}=\frac{2(m+1)}{(n+2)(n+1)}.$$

**Edit:** Indeed, as Yung-Hsiang Huang pointed in the comment, the limit is $0$ but not $2x$. In the context of Durrett's book, we let $X_n$ be the fraction of green balls after the $n$th draw, so $X_n=\frac{G_n}{n+3}$. Then $X_n$ is a non-negative martingale, and hence $X_n\rightarrow X_\infty$ a.s. We want to determine the distribution of the limit $X_\infty$. For any $x\in[0,1]$, we have
\begin{align*}
P(X_n\leq x)&=P(G_n\leq x(n+3))=\sum_{m = 0}^{[x(n+3)] - 2}\frac{2(m+1)}{(n+2)(n+1)}\\
&=\sum_{i = 1}^{[x(n+3)] - 1}\frac{2i}{(n+2)(n+1)}\\
&=\frac{\left([x(n+3)]-1\right)[x(n+3)]}{(n+2)(n+1)}, {\rm (by~Trapezoidal~rule)}
\end{align*}
where $[a]$ denotes the integer part of the real number $a$. As $n\rightarrow \infty$, we have $P(X_n\leq x)\rightarrow x^2$, hence $P(X_\infty\leq x)=x^2$, and therefore the distribution of $X_\infty$ has density $2x$, which is exactly the result in Durrett's book.

Comment: The last formula is correct. But, why the limit of that probability is 2x (along the path n -> \infty and m/n -> x)? I think it should be 0 since after a reduction, we can see the denominator is of order n^2 and the numerator is of order m.

Comment: @Yung-HsiangHuang You're correct! :) The limit is zero. Durrett made a mistake in his book.