# Limit of a probability for Polya’s Urn (from Durrett’s textbook)

Tags: calculus, probability, limits, polya-urn-model

My question comes from 1st expression in Page 227 of [Durrett’s Probability textbook (5th edition)](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Ertd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf).

It says: by taking $n \to \infty$ and $m/n \to x,$ we have $$\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!} \frac{(m+1)!(n-m)!}{(n+2)!/2} \to 2x.$$ But if we do a reduction of LHS, we have $$\frac{m+1}{(n+2)(n+1)/2} = \frac{2(m/n + 1/n)}{(1 + 2/n)(n + 1)} \to \frac{2x}{\infty} = 0.$$

Am I wrong?

If not, this is an uncorrected typo since the 3rd edition.

Comment: I'd guess it's a typo. Maybe $n+2$ was supposed to be $n+1$, or maybe $m+1$ was supposed to be $m+2$.

Comment: Durrett made a small mistake here. See my explaination in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3329473/624428).